# When logout conflict between router.navigate and breadcrumb

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage, logout

When I logout, the authToken is deleted from the localStorage, but I get a message in the console that I was redirected to the breadcrumb and when I login again, the components are displayed twice in the console when I navigate.

The breadcrumb has a problem with this.router.navigate(['/login']);

```
// To logout
  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

```
// Breadcrum problem

  this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .pipe(map(() => this.route))
      .pipe(map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
        return route;
      }))
      .pipe(filter(route => route.outlet === PRIMARY_OUTLET))
      .subscribe(route => {

        const snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
        this.breadcrumbs = [];
        const url = snapshot.url;
        const routeData = route.snapshot.data;

        console.log(routeData);
        const label = routeData.breadcrumb;
        const params = snapshot.root.params;

        this.breadcrumbs.push({
          url,
          label,
          params
        });

      });
```

Comment: Which components? Can you add the `ROUTES` from the router to the question?

Comment: I fixed the problem myself. The reason was that I subscribed to an event several times in the dashboard. Every time the component was initialized, a new subscriber was created.

My solution: With ngOnDestroy simply unsubscribe the subscriber with unsubscribe :)